# Json Column in Existing Postgres Table vs New Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have a "catalog" that I am trying to display information on. This information will be pulled from a few different tables that a user will be able to set a preference to hide a record from the respective table on their "catalog". I am running a Postgres database

So, my question is:

Would it be better (performance wise) to create a new table (table_a_to_catalog) where it would store the table_a_id and the catalog_id for the record from table_a that the user wants to hide for that catalog. Then have another table (table_b_to_catalog) to hold that connection...and so on...

OR

Would it be better to store the hide preference as a json value in the record of the catalog? So it would be something like {"table_a" => [id1, id2, id3], "table_b" => [id1, id2, id3]}

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the usecase of this catalog... If the information is readonly and you are running a job once a day to update the said catalog then json would be better. However, if you want to update information on the catelog live and and allow it to be editable then having a separate table would be best.

As for personal preference, I think keeping data in table allows more flexibility when you want to use the data for other features

Comment: if you have a separate job or function that updates the information in batches then json should be your best bet

Answer (score 1):

Having very large tables negatively impacts for performance.  Keeping "hide" view data in a postgres table means having a DB entry for each hidden entry in each catalog.  Each client application will need to filter that table for information relevant to their user, and with many users this could take considerable time.

If one simply adds a field to the user table, containing an [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html),  JSON or CSV of view data (e.g. hide preferences), that will reduce the initial load time **marginally**.  JSON would make more sense if "hiding" means simply not displaying it client-side, wheras hstore makes more sense if you wish to not send the data to the client to begin with.

I say marginally because many other factors (caching) will impact performance more than this.  You may want to look into using Redis for the application runtime and Postgres for data warehousing.

Comment: I dont believe it would need to have a db entry for each hidden field for each catalog. Using JSON (rather than hstore) you are able to do an array of ids for each "category" you want to hide. So a record for the catalog table might be

catalog_id: 1
name: Catalog Test
user_id: 5
hide: {"models": [1,2,3,4,5], "equipment": [3,6,10,39,53]} then when a catalog is generated it just has to fetch, group_by, then store in @variables those values.  I also say JSON rather than hstore because with hashes you don't have the ability to hold arrays without doing string conversion which can be messy.